# Juice-UI - buttons cause double postback

Tags: juice-ui

I have a JuiceUI button control that I use to post a form.  When I do I get a double postback.  I noticed double entries in my DB and thought maybe I was double clicking on the button, but as I have debugged this I have found out that it is not the case.  I have put a breakpoint in the postback function and it is indeed being called twice, with the stacktrace looking the same each time.  Not sure what is going on.  Any help would be appreciated.  See below my code for the button control.

```
<button id="mBtnPrevious" runat="server" onserverclick="BtnPreviousClick">Previous</button>
                                <juice:Button TargetControlID="mBtnPrevious" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a JuiceUI issue.  I resolved this by making the following change (notice the type="button"):

```
<button id="mBtnPrevious" runat="server" onserverclick="BtnPreviousClick">Previous</button>
```

to

```
<button id="mBtnPrevious" runat="server" type="button" onserverclick="BtnPreviousClick">Previous</button>
```

This appears to be a browser compatibility issue as it didn't double postback some browsers but did in others.  It looks like on some browsers it was it was using type="submit" as default which may have been causing the double postback.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you provided, I'm not seeing the behavior you've described. The page is behaving normally. There are also no events in the code for the Juice UI Button that would cause an additional postback. I'd recommend removing the  tag and start debugging from that point.